# iPhone Dev - Disabling zoom feature on UIScroll View

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview

Is there any way to make it so that the user can scroll along the UIScrollView but not be able to zoom into it? I would appreciate any help i can get... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you can answer questions like this yourself - for any object class. Just command-click on the object in question (UIScrollView) and you would have seen:

```
@property(nonatomic) float minimumZoomScale;     // default is 1.0
@property(nonatomic) float maximumZoomScale;     // default is 1.0. must be > minimum zoom scale to enable zooming
```

Answer (score 0):

Set both the **maximumZoomScale** and **minimumZoomScale** properties of the scrollview to **1.0**.

```
scrollview.maximumZoomScale = 1.0;
scrollview.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
```

or do it in Interface Builder.